# Email Alert behaves differently for 'Guest' & 'Guest License' users

Tags: community, email-template, force.com-sites, email-alert, guest-user

I have a form on **public community** & when a user submits it, an application record gets created. On the creation of the application record, have a process builder which sends an email. But this email alert is not working.

Now another scenario, where I have a **force.com site page** there is also the same form inside vf page, which also does the same thing as creating application records on form submission & in the backend we have a process builder to send an email. But here email gets delivered successfully.

So have checked all the permissions of these two profiles & seems ok. But I noticed one diffrence that the profile for the Community guest user is of '**Guest User License**' type & the profile for Force.com Guest user is of '**Guest**' type. So might be this is the problem as email works for the force.com site but not for the public community site.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the site user profile and check 'Send Emails' under General User Permission settings.